# Software Architecture question. BL creates DTOs differently by type. Is there anything better?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, prototype, dto

I've an application that has three layers:
1. data layer: exposes Entity Framework entities
2. business logic layer: queries the EF model, gets entities and should expose DTO (data transfer objects)
3. UI layer: queries BL, gets DTOs and view them.

Now I've an issue. Different part of my application needs the same DTO but with a little bit different fields. For simplicity suppose that one of my BL classes expose a DTO called Person that is needed with Name and Surname once and with Name and Date Of Birth in other place.

I'd like to hear from you what you think about my simple solution. I've come that is necessary for my UI to agree with BL on a "DTO contract" so that the two layers agree on classes. In my example I would:

a) create an abstract Person class. This class doesn't have any method nor field
b) create a method in BL called GetPerson that accepts, as parameter, a Person class
c) define two or more classes that derive from Person (suppose PersonName and PersonDOB)
d) my UI calls GetPerson passing in the needed type (like GetPerson(typeof(PersonName)))
e) BL fills in the Person class

What you think about it? Is there any better solution? I think this is not so good buy nothings better comes to my mind.

Thanks a lot.
Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar architecture in my MVC2 app. What I did:

1. BL returns a Person DTO that have Name, Surname and DoB (all those properties are a part of Person)
2. My Views work with Models, so I create specific models for each view. I would therefore have 2 Person models, ie. one with Name and Surname, other with Name and DoB.

The conversion between DTOs and models is done by a set of classes I call Adapters. In order to simplify code I use **[Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)**. This is a brilliant piece of code that will copy properties from your DTOs to Models by taking into account naming conventions and explicit configuration. Do take a look at is, as you might want to use it to populate DTOs from your EF classes.

Summing up, I have a consistent BL without any smells (this 'give me a subclass of this type' business is a bit of smell to me), and my views are working with strongly-typed models that contain only relevant data.

Comment: Thanks Jakub for your opinion. Indeed I use Automapper to map entities into DTO but the problem is that I need very different views of the same data in different places of my app. I cannot create a DTO that is the union of the the needed DTO as I would end using entities. I need to tune up my queries so I need to select just the needed information for the UI.

Comment: @Marconline - In that case I would create several DTO like you did, but accompany them with concrete methods (GetPersonFull, GetPersonBasic) that returns those concrete types without passing Type as parameter to single method. Or use interfaces to expose only certain parts of your object as Adrian suggested instead of concrete classes.

Comment: Why won't you create just a method with the type? I mean: higher level must know DTO structures so I think we are not saying anything different than saying GetPersonFull or GetPersonBasic. I think that interface stuff is perfect in theory but in practice is not so good. My DTO are big and I'd end up with a lot of interfaces... for what?

Comment: Thank you anyway, my last comment went without my thanks for your time. Marco

Comment: @Marconline - 'Why?' - Because you can call the method passing totally invalid type only to get a run-time exception. I always prefere compile-time errors to runtime exceptions. 'for what?' - I thought that THIS was your requirement: not to expose full DTO with lots of data in many places...

Comment: Yes, but my DTO would implement an interface (or deriving all from a common abstract base class) so that I'm sure at compile time that my clients are passing correct types, just like IPersonDTO. Yes the requirement is not to expose just one DTO but multiple DTOs with different views of the same content. But I think that this is not related to Interface solution. Don't you?

Comment: @Marconline - For me using interfaces allows you to expose only the subset of data without the burden of declaring new classes. And IMHO if your methods accept Type as one of the parameters then you can misuse them, ie. GetPerson(typeof(ContractDetails)). Unless you go for generics GetPerson<PersonName>() and use where T : Person to validate the type.

Comment: Ops sorry :-) 
something like GetPerson<T>() where T : IPerson. In this way I'm sure that each type requested by client was defined as accepted in the DTO contract library.

Comment: @Marconline - I'm happy my answers helped. Hope you will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things: firstly terminology.  I'm not trying to be a terminology nazi - it's just that there's some subtle differences which might affect how you think about your problem.

**DTO vs POCO**

When you talk of a DTO (Data Transfer Object) it sounds more like a POCO (Plain Old CLR Object).

POCOs:

- Are a simple data structure for passing information between layers.
- Usually this happens within an application; specifically a .Net application (managed code).
- They are usually designed with [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (Single Responsibility Principle) in mind.

In this context (the design of a specific POCO) SRP would mean either a "business" driven case of use (i.e: to show a summary of 'person' data in search results) or a generic / data centric one (i.e: provide a 'person').

DTO:

Until recently I blindly assumed that POCO == DTO; and certainly a lot of people (I think) tend to talk about them that way; I then read Martin Fowler's definition of a DTO, which is different.

- Where a POCO is used between layers of an application, a DTO is used between applications.
- The rationale is that if you have to send data over the wire - and that call is expensive - then rather than making several calls to pass several objects/data/whatever you wrap them all into a single entity and make one call.  That one entity is a DTO.

So, conceivably you might use a DTO to pass several POCO's to an external service.

**The Answer to Your Question**

When designing POCOs (and the interface between layers and components) at the top of your mind should be "why"?  There's a few different views and motivations that you consider when designing your POCOs (and DTOs):

- Responsibility: who "owns" the POCO? (i.e: what system owns the data within it).
- Use Case: is the POCO there because it make sense in a general / generic way, or, is it there for a specific / specialized purpose?
- Performance, and other runtime system qualities: DTO's are certainly influenced by performance considerations, and it's conceivable that similar thinking can be applied to POCO's when exchanging info between layers.

So, here's two approaches you might consider...

**Responsibility Driven using Concrete POCOs**

Design and build a POCO (as in an actual class or struct) that does the job you want; this will be along the lines discussed above ("business" or "generic / data centric").

This is how I currently do things.  I often have a 'fat' POCO that defines an entity in it's entirety(sometimes including other POCOs), and a 'thin' POCO for use in lists. I also tend to use seperate POCOs for saving and updating.

While it makes sense to standardize why POCOs are designed the way they are (e.g: they are all driven by the domain model, and there's only one POCO per entity) - the truth is that you'll have different motivations from different directions; my advice is to give in to this otherwise you'll end up with a system that is not flexible, easy to maintain or performant.

**Using Interfaces**

This is a more 'pure' approach.  Rather than have your application pass concrete POCOs around use interfaces instead.  Then when you build implement a POCO it can implement as many of those interfaces as you like.  For example:

```
public interface PersonID
{
    Guid PersonID { get; }
}

public interface PersonFullName
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string Lastname { get; }
    string Honorific { get; }
}

public interface PersonDateOfBirth
{
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; }
}
```

**Bonus Point**

You haven't asked for this (at least not directly) but I wouldn't tie my BL to EF - in fact I wouldn't tie it to the Data Access Layer at all.  If you do, whatever wants to use your BL will be tied to the EF as well.  You might want to consider [Dependency Inversion](http://www.morphological.geek.nz/blogs/viewpost/Peruse+Muse+Infuse/An+Introduction+to+Dependency+Inversion.aspx).

Comment: Dear Adrian, thanks for your precision on DTOs and POCOs. I'd be glad to read the article you are citing. Thanks for your solutions: if I understood well you are basically saying what I'm thinking (i.e. create different POCOs). Is it correct? Thanks, Marco

Comment: @Marconline, Yes - you're on the right track :)